# How to find the latitude and longitude using python

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

The dataset has hundreds of latitudes and longitudes. How to find a single closest latitude and longitude.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `geopy`. Here you can find how to install the client and how to perform basic geocoding tasks: https://pypi.org/project/geopy/